# Extend my "/" EXT4 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to extend the EXT4 file system with "/" as mounting point. The problem is I can't move the unallocated free space to that file system. Additionally, I can extend the other EXT4 file although it's near the unallocated space.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to bring /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7 together?  Or just trying to make /dev/sda7 larger to use the unallocated 49.42GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drive is formatted using an [MBR](https://www.disk-partition.com/gpt-mbr/mbr-vs-gpt-1004.html) (ms-dos) partition table which complicates things; it would be easier with [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), which is why it's now the Windows and Ubuntu default partition table. Let's forge ahead.

1. Run `lsb_release -a` to see what version of Ubuntu you have; we'll need to know that later.
2. Backup your data, then verify the backup matches the source data.
3. Backup again to a different destination (different drive or cloud), then verify its data matches the source data.
4. Boot from a LiveUSB with Ubuntu on it; [here's how to make it](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0). Because you did not boot from your internal drive, you can now change its partitioniing.
5. Launch [gparted](https://gparted.org/).
6. Make your root partition /**dev/sda4** larger by giving it the 49 GB unused space.
7. Commit the change by clicking on the checkmark above the map of the drive.
8. Exit from gparted, relaunch gparted, and confirm **/dev/sda4** is 49 GB larger now.
9. Delete the **/dev/sda5** *swap* partition. Commit the change by clicking on the checkmark above the map of the drive.
10. Choose **/dev/sda7** and enlarge it to the space available we just won by deleting the *swap* partition. Commit the change by clicking on the checkmark above the map of the drive.
11. Exit from gparted then relaunch it. Is **/dev/sda7** 19GB now? Good. If not, make a screenshot, exit from gparted, and come back here for help. (Unusual, but happens.)
12. DO YOU USE HIBERNATION? Then you **MUST** have a swap partition = your RAM size.
13. DO YOU USE UBUNTU 17.10 OR HIGHER? Then you can use a Swap File, which is now just as fast and far more flexible. IF you do NOT use Hibernation AND you use Ubuntu 17.10 or higher, we will skip the next step (only) which makes a new *swap* partition.
14. Make a *swap* partition equal to the size of your memory with gparted. Click the checkmark to commit the change, exit from gparted, then restart it. Does it show the *swap* partition? Good, we move on.
15. Give all remaining space to your data partition, **/dev/sda6**, by making it larger. Commit the change, exit from gparted, relaunch gparted, and confirm **/dev/sda6** took all the unallocated space.
16. Shut down the LiveUSB session of Ubuntu and reboot into Ubuntu from your internal drive.

Here's an illustration of what gparted should look like in various stages of the process. Changed sizes are approximate.

[image: gparted at various stages in the process]

**IF** you made a *swap* partition, you're finished.
If you did **not** make a *swap* partition, make a swap file and enable it.

1. At a terminal, run `sudo fallocate -h` to show [fallocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fallocate.1.html) is installed. Do you have [fallocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fallocate.1.html) on your system? If not, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install fallocate` .
2. Run `sudo fallocate -l 4G /media/WHATEVER/swapfile && sudo chmod 600 /media/WHATEVER/swapfile && ls -lh /media/WHATEVER/swapfile` where **/media/WHATEVER** is the mount point used for **/dev/sda6**, to make your *swap* file in that data partition, sets it for the use of root only, and shows you it was made. This keeps *swap* out of your root directory so it has more space.
3. Run `sudo mkswap /media/WHATEVER/swapfile && sudo swapon /media/WHATEVER/swapfile` to enable the *swap* file.
4. Run `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and paste into that file on its own line  `/media/WHATEVER/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 01` then tap <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to save and exit from [nano](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/).
5. Do `sudo swapon --show` to confirm *swap* is working, reboot back into Ubuntu on your internal drive, and do `sudo swapon --show` to confirm the changes made to /etc/fstab were saved. Now, the *swap* file will work for you thereafter.

I do this once, on every desktop Linux PC I have and maintain, (adjusting for GPT which is easier to work with). Once, it's done, and I never have to worry about it again.

Answer (score 0):

For what it may be worth, this sort of thing is *vastly* easier if you use LVM = Logical Volume Management.  (There is an `lvmify` tool at https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme .)

If you use LVM, then *physical* storage extents can be added to *logical* volumes, and more than one physical extent can be included or added.  So, you would solve your problem entirely using root-level commands to allocate a new physical area, then assign it to your "/" volume, then resize the filesystem upward.  I couldn't imagine managing a Linux system without it ...

Comment: Sadly, LVM is not Windows-friendly.